# tabularray: How do I adjust the font size of table notes?

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularray

I am using `talltblr` as a `threeparttable` replacement. The table notes work well, e.g.

```
\begin{talltblr}[note{a} = {some note}]{colspec={lll}}
...
\end{talltblr}
```

However, the table notes are typeset in the same size as the rest of the table. Changing the font size with the direct approach:

```
\begin{talltblr}[note{a} = {\footnotesize some note}]{colspec={lll}}
...
\end{talltblr}
```

This changes the font size, but not the line spacing, of the note. Is there a `tabularray` option I'm missing for the note size?

Comment: Try to add in your preamble `\SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}`.

Comment: @Celdor, perfect! That did it, thanks very much.